# Illegal float value "error" c-shell

Tags: shell-script, csh

I have a form made it with a couple of text boxes, in which I input floating numbers  and use this number to sum with other text box and put the result in a label.

I then input the values of the text boxes to a variable (xbiz and xbder) and I sum it
for example I get then this result : 
xbiz = 5.2 
xbder = 2.3

**My problem is when one of the text boxes is empty** (in blank) the script give me an error of "ILLEGAL FLOAT VALUE!" I mean if I am not input a value in any od the two variables

How can solve this problem?

Here is my code:

```
#FORM
echo "FG 999999" >> $gui_in
echo "FONT cbr18" >> $gui_in
echo "BG 901010" >> $gui_in
echo "LABEL LOCATINES" >> $gui_in
echo "FG 101090" >> $gui_in
echo "FONT cbr18" >> $gui_in
echo "BG 708787" >> $gui_in

echo "TEXT xbiz X_BOT_IZQ" >> $gui_in
echo "TEXT xbder X_BOT_DER" >> $gui_in

#Calculation
set varx = `echo " $xbder + $xbiz" | bc -l`


#After calculate the values of the two variables (xbder + xbiz) I use the result in the following line:

COM display_layer,name=comp,display=yes,number=1
COM add_pad,attributes=no,**x=${varx},y=${varx}**,symbol=${sizefido},polarity=positive,\
angle=0,mirror=no,nx=1,ny=1,dx=0,dy=0,xscale=1,yscale=1
```

Answer (score 1):

If `xbiz` or `xbder` is empty, bc will complain (bash here)

```
$ echo "5.2 + " | bc -l
(standard_in) 2: syntax error
```

You're going to need something like (untested)

```
if (! $?xbiz) set xbiz = 0
set varx = `echo " 5.2 + $xbiz" | bc -l`
if (! $?xbder) set xbder = 0
set vary = `echo " 5.2 + $xbder" | bc -l`
```

Comment: Hi Glenn, I am still getting the illegal floating point error" I realize that the number "5" that I adding or summing is not 5, rather is 5.2 so the formula is going to be : set varx = `echo " 5.2 + $xbiz" | bc -l` Do you have another idea how to solve this??

Comment: What is the content of the `xbiz` variable?

Comment: Hi Glenn: the content of the xbiz variable is coming from a input text boxes, generally are numbers like 2.4, 4.15,etc. my problems is when the text box is empty or "0" there I get the error illegal float point value!!

Comment: Well, in those cases, you have to change the value.

Comment: How do I change the values Gelnn? I am so new in shell script, how do I get rid of the illegal float point error, thanks for your valuable help!

Comment: Do you mean change the values of the imput? I can do that, always is going to work with integer (like number 4, 5, etc)and float points (like 1.2, 2.5, etc), because this is for calculate "x" and "y" for a manufacturing printed circuit board software, and it works with shell script,

Comment: If you're new to shell scripting, do not use csh, use bash or ksh. Make that change immediately.

Comment: I can not change to other because this software works only with scripts made in c shell, thanks anyway